# Swift - CGAffineTransform rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform, rotatetransform

I have an `UIImageView` to rotate in a `draw` function.

```
public var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    rotateIcon(by: progress)
}

private func rotateIcon(by angle: CGFloat) {
    if imageView == nil {
        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bt_info"))
        imageView?.center = center
        imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
        addSubview(imageView!)
    }
    imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
}
```

Below is the output attached for the above snippet.

[image]

When I set the frame size, the `imageView` shrink and expands as it rotates. I would like to maintain the size as the `imageView` rotates. What am I missing?

Comment: Quick test -- I'm not seeing the same results... can you update your post with the full code necessary to reproduce this?

Comment: @DonMag I have added the source to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/md3brf8rk24xwu7/TestApp.zip?dl=0). I have used `UIView` instead of `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - the code you posted in your question does not match the code in your Dropbox project...

In your project, you're doing this:

```
private func rotateScannerIcon(by angle: CGFloat) {
    if testView == nil {
        testView = UIView()
        testView?.backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(testView!)
    }
    
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    testView?.center = centerPoint
    testView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 24.0, height: 24.0)

    testView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
}
```

With that code, you are changing the frame size ***after*** a rotation transform has been applied... and the actual view is no longer "square."

If you move the position / size code inside your "create" block:

```
private func rotateScannerIcon(by angle: CGFloat) {
    if testView == nil {
        testView = UIView()
        testView?.backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(testView!)

        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        testView?.center = centerPoint
        testView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
    }
    
    testView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
}
```

The "squeezing" of the frame no longer happens.

Overriding `draw()` is probably not the best approach, though. That is primarily done when UIKit view updates are not sufficient to handle the layout - such as when using stroke/fill on paths.

So, I would suggest a couple changes.

Create your subview (`UIView` or `UIImageView` or whatever) when the custom view subclass is initialized, and size/position it with auto-layout constraints.

Then, when you update the `progress` property, apply the rotation transform.

As an example, here's a modified version of your `TestView` class:

```
public class TestView: UIView {
    
    public var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            rotateScannerIcon(by: (progress * CGFloat(Double.pi)))
        }
    }
    
    internal var testView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        // create the view (or image view)
        testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        // add it to self
        addSubview(testView)
        
        // let's use auto-layout constraints
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain the view to 24 x 24, centered in self
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }

    private func rotateScannerIcon(by angle: CGFloat) {
        testView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the misplacement!!